# Unit Test with code coverage and formal output documentation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage

What are some options for unit testing tools that show code coverage including lines of code that have actually been tested.

Needs to create a graphical report to show the output (not just an xml file), showing pass fail and coverage in a format readable by nontechnical people.

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean by 'how' I cannot see how this could be automated, you have to look at the test to see what is being exercised by a particular test. Code coverage is the most blunt of instruments to know if code is 'well tested' or not.

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'formal' who is the intended audience? No one but devs should really care what is passing when (at unit level).

Comment: I have to show the unit test result to people who do not really know much about computers, and they want to see that everything worked fine.

Comment: While code coverage != well tested, there are a lot of demand by non developers to "See" the test results and coverage, large corporations and government will have contracts that specify what the code coverage must be.  For good or bad that's the reality, as developers we should be using coverage a "ONE" tool to making sure things work as expected, or find untested code sections.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of tools, Visual Studio 2013 Pro even has a build in coverage tool.

Here are some commercial tools I have personal experience with:

1. [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) - Automated test runner with a coverage report (use everyday)
2. [DotCover](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) - Sold coverage tool by jet brains that ties into resharper really well (used until I found nCrunch)
3. [NCover](https://www.ncover.com/) - It was really the first and still running strong (creates an xml report that then is consumed by Reportbuilder to make graphical reports)

For free tools I like [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover), basically a free open source version of nCover, even uses the same report gen tools and is based on the now dead (in maintenance mode) [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4). This is what I use on our Jenkins build servers.

If you are looking to get this on a build server [Jetbrains Team City](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity) has dotCover built in for both the free and enterprise versions and TFS has it own coverage tool as well.  For doing [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) there are plugins for displaying the report but you have to set up and run the tools as part of the build process.

Answer (score 0):

Showing how it's been tested, I haven't seen.

[Dot Cover](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) is a pretty all encompassing plug in.  It has an export option *I believe*. I'd suggest taking it for a free spin and seeing if it fits your needs.

[Test Driven .net](http://www.testdriven.net/) may be a cheaper solution for you - and is a pretty good alternative.

Comment: TestDriven.net uses the community nCover under the hood